# Android studio xml not allowing me to reference id resources

Tags: android, xml

I recently started using android studio (formerly eclipse) and when trying to create an xml page there have been problems referncing the id resrouces I've set up. 
(Relative Layout)

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/table"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

<Button
    android:text="@string/menu"
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/table"
    />
```

But for some reason it says it cannot resolve the android:layout_above = "@id/table", so I checked in the R file and found that it exists under id.

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f080003;
    public static final int menu=0x7f080001;
    public static final int order=0x7f080000;
    public static final int table=0x7f080002;
}
```

I don't think it's the way I'm referencing it because the @id/table claims the resrouce doesn't exist even before I've run the app.

Any help would be appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Did you try @+id/table

Comment: try to rebuild project

Comment: Do have only problem to reference the button **table**? Can you successfully reference **menu** button?

Comment: @Nizam Yeah I've already tried using the + sign but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @helleye No I can't reference any of the other elements that're shown on the R file.

Comment: Can you show your complete xml and the activity, at least onCreate() and (if different) the method where you try to reference those resources?